# Adding a number to the end of a 4 digit number in a cell, while ignoring every other number

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to Add a number to the end of a 4 digit number that is in a cell, while ignoring every other number.

[image]

The code adds zeros to everything and I wanted to leave out all 5 digit numbers.

```
Sub leadingzeros()

Dim cel As Range, rg As Range
Dim zc As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rg = Range("G2") 'First cell to be converted
Set rg = Range(rg, rg.Worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, rg.Column).End(xlUp)) 'all data in that column
rg.NumberFormat = "@"


On Error Resume Next
For Each cel In rg.Cells
    If IsNumeric(cel.Value) Then
        d = Val(cel.Value)
        cel.Value = Format(d, "00000")
        cel.Value = "0" & d
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: `rg.NumberFormat = "00000"` adds a leading zero to four digit numbers, leaves 5 digit numbers alone and retains the underlying raw numerical value. Also, see Cell Formatting, Number, Special for Zip Code and the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) for retrieving the formated (as displyed) number.

Comment: One of my favourite zip/zip+4 custom number formats is `[Color5][>99999]00000-0000;[Color3]00000`.

Comment: Either cell formatting as @Jeeped suggested or a simple `=IF()` formula in the next column could solve this pretty easily.

Comment: Do you want the cell contents to **be** "07405" or do you just want the cell to **display** 7405 as 07405?  (If you actually want the contents to include the leading "0", just remove the line in your code which says `cel.Value = "0" & d`.)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it if your only issue is leaving out anything with a length of 5.

```
Sub leadingzeros()

Dim cel As Range, rg As Range
Dim zc As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rg = Range("G2") 'First cell to be converted
Set rg = Range(rg, rg.Worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, rg.Column).End(xlUp)) 'all data in that column
rg.NumberFormat = "@"


On Error Resume Next
For Each cel In rg.Cells
    If IsNumeric(cel.Value) and Len(cel.Value) <> 5 Then 'This could be changed to be less than 5, or equals 4, or whatever the true criteria is
        d = Val(cel.Value)
        cel.Value = Format(d, "00000")
        cel.Value = "0" & d
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simplify your macro a bit, change the `Format` statement slightly, and it should run fine: No need for `If`'s, `OnError`'s, etc

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub leadingzeros()

Dim cel As Range, rg As Range
Dim zc As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rg = Range("G2", Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))

rg.NumberFormat = "@"

For Each cel In rg
    cel.Value = Format(cel, "00000")
Next cel

End Sub
```

---

Of course, if you only need the display, and not the actual cell contents to have the five digits, you could simply custom format the column without changing the values into text.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a VBA-based solution, but if you wanted to do this directly in Excel:

```
=text(G2, "00000")
```

Or, if this is a table:

```
=text([@ZIP], "00000")
```

I realize this means adding a column, but maybe the advantages of ease and transparency make it worthwhile.

If you're okay with the value being the same but the display having the leading zeroes, there is a zip-code format under "special" formats.  This would be the same as having a custom format of "00000."